# Laminate Planking will not "Click-in"

Tags: flooring, laminate-floor

So, yesterday while trying to install some flooring (Pergo -Timbercraft). I have installed it in a previous room before and had no issue. However this time while trying to fit it into my bay window on piece (the second last one...) it will not click into place. I can't get it into place no matter how hard I try. Below are some pictures. Sorry the orientation on the flooring shows it as vertical, not horizontal which would be correct - I don't know how to change it on here.
[image: Picture of remaining gap] 
[image: Picture of bay window]

As you can see, the angle against the wall is quite small meaning as I am hammering it in (to close the gap) most of the force is just going into the pieces behind it (not to the right as it should be). Any ideas I can try?

Added picture to show the angle.
[image]

Comment: manufacturing defect perhaps

Comment: Is this type of connection supposed to tilt into place? Most are these days.

Comment: All the boards that are connecting into place are fine - I can't see any defects in the groves. And to @isherwood yes, you click the base into place (the long side) and then tap the short side in. I think the issue here is the angle where I would tap. I added another picture.

Comment: Remove the piece and make sure there is no dirt or bent edge preventing the gap closing.

Comment: @SolarMike I did that last night and it got to the same point again. I even blew the grooves out with a can of compressed air (like what you would use to clean a keyboard with) so that the pipe was small and could fit in the small spaces.

Comment: Is there going to be an edging strip fitted? if so, you could make a notch in the tapered side and make a lever to act on the notch (think like turning a screwdriver) causing the force to be more direct...

Comment: Good idea I will try that when I get home.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into similar issue in past.  My solution was to click the 2 boards for the last row together first and then add both boards as a unit.

Answer (score 1):

I normally would use a flooring hook to be able to hit the plate at the right angle:
[image: Flooring Hook]

If that doesn't work, I would remove the plate and check if it or the ones around it aren't damaged, and replace the damaged one with a new one.

Comment: I have tried that, I think the issue is at the side the angle is slight enough to make it as if I am tapping down into the long side of the board not, the side (which is where I need to tap).

Comment: Thanks for adding a picture to clarify the angle. Yes, that angle could cause the flooring hook to be ineffective.

I would say that your flooring has been placed in the wrong order. I would normally start at the window and work towards the door to be sure that there is room to click the plates together. 
In this case, since it's too late to redo the whole floor,  I would do as suggested in the other answer below, to click the 2 boards together for the last row.

Answer (score 0):

Under the following assumptions,

- there will eventually be a quarter round or other trim strip to cover the gap between the laminate material and the existing trim around the window (which will help hold the laminate in place regardless of if it's clicked-in or not
- this isn't likely to be a high-traffic or high-stress area for your flooring material
- you just can't get it to click, even after you've checked that the groove is clean and you've tried using a pull bar and/or a flooring hook

My next step would be to use a wedge-shaped shim between the board and the wall of windows, as a way to help your hammering/pulling force get directed in the right orientation.

If that doesn't work, as a final resort, I would just cut the groove off the short end of the piece (but leave the finished surface intact, and leave the groove on the long edge intact, since it seems to be seating correctly) and slide it in place so it's flush without that gap showing. With no groove, you should be able to butt the finished surface up tight without having to force anything to click. The quarter round (or other trim) will hold it in place well enough. If it does move enough for the gap to reappear, you can tack that one board in place with trim nail(s) hidden under the quarter round.

An advantage of floating laminate flooring is that when you have a challenging spot like this, you can try something out - and if it doesn't work, just replace the board and try something else - all you've lost is a few minutes of time.